# flex: 1120 access to undefined property

Tags: apache-flex

I was trying to place some simple effects on an image using HBox using Hslider/Checkbox.

I am unable to incorporate the required effects on the image.I an getting the errors 
"120 access to undefined property" ....poinying to "HSlider/change".

What can be the error/solution to this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
      <mx:HBox top="10" left="10">
       <mx:HSlider top="-10" left="100" value="-10" toolTip="Rotation" 
             change="myImg.rotation=event.currentTarget"    
                            liveDragging="true">
       </mx:HSlider>
      </mx:HBox>
      <mx:CheckBox label="Visible" change="myImg.visible=event.currentTarget.selected"          
          selected="true"/>
      <mx:Image name="myImg" source="file:///C|/Users/terry/Desktop/test/myImage.jpg" 
                       height="100" top="60" left="30" rotation="-10">
           <mx:filters>
             <mx:DropShadowFilter />
        </mx:filters>
        </mx:Image>
    </mx:Application>
```

further in the "Hslider/Change" attribute it should be

```
"myImg.rotation=event.currentTarget.valueOf()" or 
"myImg.rotation=event.currentTarget.value"
```

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Could you post more code so we can better understand the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the code.

This might be a copy/paste issue, but the code snippet you sent has one major problem:

The Image name is *myImg*, whereas it's referred to as *myimg* throughout the snippet.  Let us know if that's a copy typo, or an actual bug.

---

The *name=* for your Image should be *id=*.  When you refer to the component within the rest of the application, you do so via its ID which wasn't set.

```
<mx:Image id="myImg" source...
```

Comment: "1120: access to undefined property"
"Line breakpoint starter" ....pointing to "HSlider/change" i suppose