# 1120: Access of undefined property [instantiated variable]? (Flex)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compiler-errors, flex4.5, undefined-reference

I have looked at questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309058/error-1120-access-of-undefined-property), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854327/1120-access-of-undefined-property-stop), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826822/error-1120access-of-undefined-property) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484005/flex-1120-access-to-undefined-property), but none of these seem to describe my problem?

I am declaring these variables:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import assets.Page;
        public var oneTwo:Page = new Page("...");
        public var oneThree:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFour:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFive:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneSix:Page = new Page("...");
```

... are referencing objects that do exist, and Flex is okay with the constructors of each of these items. Next, I try to set other properties of these objects:

```
        oneThree.next = oneFour;
        oneThree.prev = oneTwo;
        oneFour.next = oneFive;
        oneFour.prev = oneThree;
        oneFive.next = oneSix;
        oneFive.prev = oneFour;
```

etc. Now, when I click each of these, Flex highlights the variable in each instance, and recognizes all of them as valid during coding. But compilation gives:

```
-1120: Access of undefined property oneThree.
-1120: Access of undefined property oneFour.
-1120: Access of undefined property oneFour.
-1120: Access of undefined property oneFive.
```

and so on, one for each time each variable  is used (so twelve times in the case here). You can see I made some public and some protected, this does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This][1] question led me to the solution.

The variables in the second code block need to be edited within their own function, getting:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import assets.Page;
        public var oneTwo:Page = new Page("...");
        public var oneThree:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFour:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFive:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneSix:Page = new Page("...");

        oneThree.next = oneFour;
        oneThree.prev = oneTwo;
        oneFour.next = oneFive;
        oneFour.prev = oneThree;
        oneFive.next = oneSix;
        oneFive.prev = oneFour;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

instead of this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import assets.Page;
        public var oneTwo:Page = new Page("...");
        public var oneThree:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFour:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneFive:Page = new Page("...");
        protected var oneSix:Page = new Page("...");

        protected function _init():void
        {
            oneThree.next = oneFour;
            oneThree.prev = oneTwo;
            oneFour.next = oneFive;
            oneFour.prev = oneThree;
            oneFive.next = oneSix;
            oneFive.prev = oneFour;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

that took care of the errors for me. Hope this helps someone else!!